# Can I use a space in an option name/key?

Tags: options

Is there any reason at all that I can't use a space in a WP option name/key?  Ex.

`update_option( 'my option name', 'abc' );`

I can't find anything that states I can't, but every example uses an underscore instead.  I want to know if using a space will actually break anything now or in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than general WordPress practice (http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/) which encourages spaces to always be replaced with - in file names and _ for other purposes, there isn't a set reason that you can't use spaces in an option name.

From my tests, there is no technical reason to limit you from using a space.

(edit) looking further, the SQL is:
$row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT autoload FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name = %s", $option ) );

so any escaped value should work but just to be safe, you should always use esc_sql() as it doesn't do it specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a space, but it is a little bit annoying to select this key per keyboard. Normally, you can use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Arrow</kbd> to select a string. Hyphens and spaces are stop points for this kind of selection.

Comment: also maybe worth noting that any leading or trailing spaces in the option name will be removed via [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: @toscho I don't understand why you're mentioning selection via keyboard. I'm asking about programmatically setting and getting WP options.

Comment: @ggutenberg Because someone has to edit the code or write queries for the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use any characters in the settings (except maybe quotes).
These are all valid option names:

```
"my option name"
"my:option name"
"MY->OPTION_NAME"
"My/Option/Name"
"my-option-name"
```

**Important Limitations**

1. Option-Names must be max 64 characters long!

If you specify a longer name, the option name will be truncated to fit 64 characters *in DB* (not in code). So this makes it impossible to retrieve the option value again. Always ensure your option name is max 64 characters long.

2. Option-Names are case insensitive!

If you save an option `APIKEY` you can also access it via `apikey`

3. Take care to not accidentally use WP core option names! You should always prefix your option names.

**My tipp**

Create a small function that you use to prefix/sanitize your option keys in every plugin/theme, which takes care of the restrictions for you, like this here:

```
// Makes sure that all option names have same structure.
function sanitize_option_key( $name ) {
    $prefix = 'my_';
    // Basic sanitation: Trim and make option name lower case.
    $name = strtolower( trim( $name ) );
    // Ensure the option does not contain spaces
    $name = str_replace( array( '-', ' ' ), '_', $name ); 
    // Prefix prevents any collisions with WP
    $name = $prefix . $name;
    // Also check the max-length
    if ( strlen( $name ) > 64 ) { 
        error_log( 'WARNING - Option name is too long and was truncated: ' . $name );
        $name = substr( $name, 0, 64 ); 
    }
    return $name;
}

// Using this function:

update_option( sanitize_option_key( 'option value' ), 'test' );
// option is saved in DB as 'my_option_value'

echo get_option( sanitize_option_key( 'Option_Value' ) ); 
// will output 'test';
```